# How to read list of maps

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a TestNG scenario method as

```
@Then("User Enters Data")
public void feedData(IDataReader dataTable) {
    List<Map<String,String>> data= dataTable.getAllRows();
 }
```

Data is being returned as a list of map as follows:

```
[{TextBox=TextValue-1,DropDown=DD-1, Description=Desc-1},
{TextBox=TextValue-2,DropDown=DD-2, Description=Desc-2},
{TextBox=TextValue-3,DropDown=DD-3, Description=Desc-3}]
```

Selenium script required to feed the above data in the UI. How to read this hence values can be feed to UI in a sequential order. Like

```
TextBox=TextValue-1,DropDown=DD-1, Description=Desc-1
```

Then click on save button.

Comment: How does `TextBox`, `DropDown` and `Description` maps to the WebElement attributes?

Comment: The Text box value will be send to SendKeys method as string. Similarly Dropdown value will be send to drop down     //div[@id='div1' and text()='" + DivValue + "'] DivValue  as String.

Comment: How about `DropDown` and `Description`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase the data is being returned is a *`List`* of *`Map<String,String>`* as follows:

```
[{TextBox=TextValue-1, DropDown=DD-1, Description=Desc-1}, {TextBox=TextValue-2, DropDown=DD-2, Description=Desc-2}, {TextBox=TextValue-3, DropDown=DD-3, Description=Desc-3}]
```

To read the *`keys`* and *`values`* you can use the following solution:

```
// System.out.println(list);
// [{TextBox=TextValue-1, DropDown=DD-1, Description=Desc-1}, {TextBox=TextValue-2, DropDown=DD-2, Description=Desc-2}, {TextBox=TextValue-3, DropDown=DD-3, Description=Desc-3}]
for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println(key);
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TextBox
TextValue-1
DropDown
DD-1
Description
Desc-1
TextBox
TextValue-2
DropDown
DD-2
Description
Desc-2
TextBox
TextValue-3
DropDown
DD-3
Description
Desc-3
```